# Where to implement applicationWillResignActive(_:)?

Tags: ios, swift, lifecycle, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

In order for the `ViewController` to "***do something specific***" just before the app goes into the background state...

I am to understand that this sort of thing is generally handled inside the 
*`applicationWillResignActive(_:)`* method, *but this method resides inside the `AppDelegate` class, not the `ViewController`.*

***This is my first time doing lifecycle related stuff on IOS, and so I'm not sure whether to:***

1) Call a `ViewController` method from inside the `AppDelegate` class.  This would mean that I have to change the method from private to public.

2) Have the `ViewController` `implement UIApplicationDelegate`

***PS -*** Is it okay to just delete the `AppDelegate` class as long as the `ViewController` implements `UIApplication` delegate instead?

**EDIT: I should add that this is a single-page app with only one view controller (well, I suppose it will have a settings view controller eventually... but the 'ViewController' that I am referring to will never be popped off the stack).**

Thanks!

Comment: I'd think a view controller is just that - a class that controls it's "root" view. By that I mean you *should not* have it "do something specific" with regard to the app going into the background. Instead, design your app to (a) have a view controller "do something specific" when it's `viewWillDisappear` and have your app "do something specific" when the `applicationWillResignActive`.

Comment: You can use NotificationCenter or you can implement a method in your AppDelegate to get the current visible viewController and call a custom method on it, a better approach for this last method will be use a BaseViewController for all our App viewControllers

Comment: Use notification named as UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification. This will notify when app going to resignActive state.

Comment: dfd the ViewController will never be dismissed.  It is a single page app with only one ViewController.

Comment: @Reinier Melian please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't delete the AppDelegate unless you have a really good reason. This isn't a good reason.

For your scenario I would investigate using `NotificationCenter` to observe the `UIApplicationWillResignActive` event. This event is fired every time the application will enter the background.

For more information see: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622973-uiapplicationwillresignactive)

e.g.

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(youFunction), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
}

func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated: animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: like dfd is suggesting above, now I am thinking maybe I was asking the wrong question... and that I might as well "do something specific" in viewWillDisappear since that is presumably called at the same time as the applicationWillResignActive(_:) method anyway. :T

Comment: That's not technically true, `viewWillDisappear` is used for ViewController navigation and not UIApplication events. If you add a breakpoint within `viewWillDisappear` and press the home button you'll see it's not triggered.

Comment: yep I'm doing that right now... and googling "viewWillDisappear not called" :S

Comment: Yep, so that's where my answer comes in. You should observe the `. UIApplicationWillResignActive` notification from `NotificationCenter` to be alerted when the user presses the home button.

Comment: I understand.. forgive me.. I appreciate your answer... I'm just waiting to see if anyone approves any of the other options suggested in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use NotificationCenter

In YourViewController

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController {

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadTableData(_:)), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    }
}

func reloadTableData(_ notification: Notification) {
}
```